# How can you see if a file is a binary in cvs

Tags: cvs

I'd like to check if a file was added as binary, but I don't know what to look for in cvs status or cvs log.. any hints?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
cvs status -v binaryfile.gif
```

This will show the status of the binaryfile.gif and the Sticky Options will show `-kb` if it is a binary file.

Answer (score 1):

Um, my CVS days are long since over (good!), but wasn't it the `-kb` option what you need to look for? I think `cvs status -v` will show you this.